# Current year with 4 digits in elm 0.19.1

Tags: date, elm

How can I do a function to get the current year with 4 digits using ELM 0.19.1? I have read something but nothing works with 0.19.1.

Signature:

```
getCurrentYear : Int
```

Execution:

```
getCurrentYear => 2020
```

Edit:

Maybe executing `new Date().getFullYear()` javascript code?

Comment: That fundamentally isn't how pure functional languages work. You can get the current Date via the Elm "runtime system", but you can't write an Elm function which returns a different value at different times.

Comment: @RobinZigmond how can I get de year via runtime system?

Comment: see my answer below. Unfortunately there's no simple "just do this" but I've tried to explain how to do this sort of thing within the Elm Architecture, with helpful links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way would be to pass the year in via [flags](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/flags.html) when you start the app, since the current year isn't likely to change in the course of the application running.  In that case, you can use the snippet of JavaScript you suggested ([ellie example](https://ellie-app.com/8C85bmT2VNPa1)):

```js
    Elm.Main.init({ 
      node: document.querySelector('main'), 
      flags: {
        year: new Date().getFullYear(),
      } 
    });
```

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, p, text)


type alias Flags =
    { year : Int }


main : Program Flags Model Msg
main =
    Browser.element
        { init = \flags -> ( Model flags.year, Cmd.none )
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = \_ -> Sub.none
        }


type alias Model =
    { year : Int }


type Msg
    = NoOp


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        NoOp ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    p [] [ text "The year is ", text (String.fromInt model.year) ]
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Time.now`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/Time#now) to request the current time, as [Robin Zigmond's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61260269/2688) suggests, however that is pointing to Elm 0.18 documentation (for [elm-lang/core](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Date) instead of [elm/time](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/Time)).  For 0.19, you need both a [`Time.Posix`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/Time#Posix) and a [`Time.Zone`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/Time#Zone) in order to call [`Time.toYear`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/Time#toYear).  You can chain [`Time.now`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/Time#now) (a `Task` producing a `Posix` value) and [`Time.here`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/Time#here) (a `Task` producing a `Zone` with the current time zone offset) to retrieve those values in one `Cmd`.  Here's an example ([also on ellie](https://ellie-app.com/8C8ctqYfkwha1))

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, p, text)
import Task exposing (Task)
import Time


type alias Flags =
    { year : Int }


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.element
        { init = \() -> ( Model 0, whatYearIsIt |> Task.perform GotYear )
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = \_ -> Sub.none
        }


whatYearIsIt : Task x Int
whatYearIsIt =
    Task.map2 Time.toYear Time.here Time.now


type alias Model =
    { year : Int }


type Msg
    = GotYear Int


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        GotYear year ->
            ( { model | year = year }, Cmd.none )


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    p [] [ text "The year is ", text (String.fromInt model.year) ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realised my documentation links were out of date. (One of my problems with Elm is how hard it can be to find up to date docs, especially with the transition from 0.18 to 0.19.) I will update my own answer.

Comment: Yeah, the 0.19 transition was tricky, in part because they moved from the `elm-lang` organization to just `elm`, so the "latest" version of all of the `elm-lang` core packages are still on 0.18

Answer (score 7):

As I already said in my comment, it's impossible to define a function in Elm that returns the current year. You have to get such information from the Elm runtime system (which is basically JavaScript, but you don't have to write it yourself). This happens via [commands](https://guide.elm-lang.org/effects/http.html), where you tell the runtime system to do something for you. But note that you can't simply retrieve the "return value" of that command and get it back into your Elm code. Instead you have to pass it into a function that can convert it into a "message" (see basic Elm Architecture tutorial [here](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/), it's fundamental to understand this before you can do anything with Elm) - this then allows you to store the value in your Model and thereby display it in your app.

These patterns do take some getting your head around, especially if you're not used to pure functional programming - but once you get used to it the benefits are huge, including a near guaranteed absence of runtime errors, and greatly enhanced ability to reason about your code.

For getting the year specifically, it looks like you need [this library](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/Time), which gives you (as `now`) a `Task` rather than a `Cmd`. You can use `Task.perform` to convert it to a command, which is documented [here](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Task) - in fact it even gives an example that matches your use case quite closely - I'll copy it here for posterity:

```
import Time  -- elm install elm/time
import Task

type Msg
  = Click
  | Search String
  | NewTime Time.Posix

getNewTime : Cmd Msg
getNewTime =
  Task.perform NewTime Time.now
```

You'll have to fill this in to fit your own use case, in particular your own `Msg` type. But it gives a good basic outline. To get the user's current year, you need to replace the `Time.Posix` type with `Int`, and the `Time.now` command with `(Task.map2 Time.toYear Time.here Time.now)`, as explained by @bdukes in his answer.

Comment: Was the ever a more perfectly answered answer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Library link says "`NOTE — this package moved to elm/core`"

Comment: Apologies, turned out the documentation I was looking at wa out of date - Elm 0.19 has a lot of breaking changes from 0.18 and as I don't actually use Elm that much I didn't realise I was looking at the old stuff. I've updated now, let me know if you have any more problems.

Comment: @bkspurgeon thanks, I've seen enough great SO answers to know this effort isn't even in the top 100 (you can probably add a zero or two to that) - but I do make an effort to explain things as well as I can, and if it helps the OP, and others later with similar questions, that's all I can hope for.

Comment: I am very grateful to you and I very much appreciate the work you have done but the other colleague (@bdukes) has also done it and in the end I have decided to use flags. I'm sorry

Comment: No need to apologise, he gave a great answer :)